# Textwrapping a paragraph that contains variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I have the following code:

```
animal = str(input("A prey animal (singular): "))
habitat = str(input("A habitat, such as savannah or rainforest: "))
action_verb = str(input("A motion related action verb (ending with ing) such as moving or running: "))
onomatopeia = str(input("A sound an animal makes, such as growl or bark: "))
number_1 = int(input("An integer between 2 and 9: "))
predators = str(input("A predator that eats your prey animal (plural): "))
insects = str(input("A terrible swarming insect that lives in your chosen habitat (plural): "))
number_2 = number_1**number_1*100

print("\tAlong came a", animal, action_verb, "through the", habitat + ". All of a sudden," 
    "\nthere was a loud", onomatopeia, "and the", animal, "looked around for a good place to" 
    "\nhide. There was a pack of", number_1, predators, "coming right towards the poor", animal+ 
    ". However, \nall of the", predators, "had to run, because", number_2, insects, "were"
    "swarming the\n", predators, "and they had to hightail it out "
    "of there. \n\"Phew, that's a relief,\" thought the", animal + ", \"man, I really could" 
    "have \nbeen toast if not for those", insects + ".\"")
```

I don't really know what to do here, because I can't get it to output into a paragraph with lines set to 80 characters each because of the variables. I know that there's a textwrap module, but it only works with strings from what I have tried. Does anyone know how I could get this to be formatted nicely when it outputs?

Comment: Parse the string with `f'Along came a {animal} ...'` , then do the wrapping

Answer (score 1):

You could use textwrap, but first format it like: `"This variable {} is in the sentence".format(variable)`

Answer (score 1):

here is another formatting system.

```
print(f"{current_variable} said hello!")
```

when current_variable is `James` it format string to this

```
"James said hello!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Along the correct @Adam's format string answer you may use the more recent f string as:

print(f"\tAlong came a, {animal}, {action_verb}, through the, {habitat}. All of a sudden,.....etc"